# django_filters returns True is not a valid field when filtering through rest api

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Got in my model serializer such field like **is_favorited** and others

```
is_favorited = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_is_favorited(self, obj):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    if user.is_anonymous:
        return False
    qs = Favorite.objects.filter(user=user, recipe=obj)
    return len(qs) > 0
```

my **model viewset** contains

```
queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
filterset_fields = (
    'is_favorited',
        )
```

in Postman i get this bad request when trying to filter by this boolean field
[image]

Comment: dont understand: is there a place where i should match True = 1, False = 0 or True,False should be lowercase? Tried lowercase true,false - the same error

Comment: Is `is_favorited` a field or property in `Recipe` model?

Comment: it's a property

Comment: Could you share in your question details of the `is_favorited` property?  Django does not support filtering by property only by fields defined in the model.

Comment: have a look in my first part of code, where "get_is_favorited" method

Comment: By configuring `filterset_fields = ('is_favorited',)` you drive django to execute a filter like `Recipe.objects.all().filter(is_favorited=True)`. This will not work since there is no `is_favorited` column/field. Does such query work if you execute it in shell? Please, write the expected query like `Recipe.objects.all().filter(...)` (change `...` with your logic) and then we could help you to write proper filter that can be used in your view.

Comment: in shell isnt workink ofcourse)
when i filter by "is_favorite" i want the current queryset = Recipes.objects.all() to get filtered also by records that are in table Favorite (user + recipe fields)
The recipe is considered favorited if recipe is in Favorite table for current user

Comment: decided to use get_queryset in order to filter simple queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decided to use get_queryset in order to filter simple queries.